# How Old is `language=JavaScript1.1` in Tag?

Tags: javascript, history

I was working on a project last weekend for some people refactoring some very old code, and I ran into this in a JS tag.  `language=JavaScript1.1`  What era of JavaScript was this?

Comment: Maybe it was from the _JavaScript 1.1_ era..

Comment: It can be hard to judge because outdated tutorials stick around forever. I'm sure people are writing code like that *today*. Crockford and others recommend that the "type" and "language" attributes be left off entirely for new (JavaScript) code.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history .  Has JavaScript versions in there.  @Pointy is right, you can't tell when that was actually created.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history

Comment: This project's so old I'm pretty sure that tag was considered proper back in the day.

Comment: Everything was considered proper at one point :D

Comment: @tymeJV True true.  Let's just say there was a lot of `eval()` and `where() {}` code to deal with.

Comment: Like looking into a time capsule...unless you have to remediate the code...then...sorry :\

Comment: If someone, maybe @MiklosAubert or @ DanielGimenez want to put their comments as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Javascript 1.1 was released in 1996, and supplanted by 1.2 in 1997.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history)

Comment: Close enough of a year estimate.